# Stubbing a method twice with PowerMockito to return different values each time

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, stub, powermockito

I have a method `underTest` in Class `BeingTested` for which I'm making unit tests. The method has two calls to a private method `calledTwice`, which returns a Document. I need to stub `calledTwice` so it returns a different Document on each call (doc1 on the first, and doc2 on the second). `calledTwice` accepts as an argument an instance of the class `AnotherClass`, and there are changes made to the instance of this class between the two calls to `underTest`.
This is how I attempted to do this:

```
Class BeingTested{
    public void underTest{
        /*some code*/
        Document doc = calledTwice(AnotherClass o);
        /*some code, with changes made to o*/
        doc = calledTwice(AnotherClass o);
        /*some code*/
    }
} 

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(BeingTested.class)
class TestClass{
    @InjectMocks
    BeingTested beingTested;

    public void testMethod(){
        Document doc1 = new Document().append("someField", "someValue");
        Document doc2 = new Document().append("error", "Error");
        /*some code*/
        PowerMockito.when(beingTested, "calledTwice").thenReturn(doc1).thenReturn(doc2);
        /*some code*/
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, as it ends up actually called `calledTwice`. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Mockito instead

```
 Mockito.when(beingTested, "calledTwice").thenReturn(doc1).thenReturn(doc2);
```

Comment: calledTwice is a private method. I've edited the question to reflect that. Sorry for that. However, using Mockito.when is not applicable for an object and String as parameters